# Delete results in subquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to delete the results of the subquery below. How do I do that?

```
delete
from mytable
where rowid in (select rowid, count(*) as count from mytable group by mygroup having count > 50)
```

Did not work:

> [1] [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (sub-select returns 8
>   columns - expected 1)

Comment: The sub-query should only return one column - rowid. Besides, the sub-query group by is invalid.

Comment: If you had a `mygroup` with 51 entries your (corrected) subquery would return one (effectively randon) `rowid` - is that what you want?

Comment: The idea is to delete all rows that have more than 50 aggregated results when grouped by mygroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check this [page](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-in/), you would notice that when using `IN` and a subquery:

> A list of values is a fixed value list or a result set of **one column** returned by a subquery. The returned type of the expression and values in the list must be the same.

Your mistake here is that your subquery is returning more than 1 column (rowid and count).

To fix that you can try this:

```
delete
from  mytable
where rowid in (select rowid 
                from (select rowid, 
                             count(*) as count 
                      from mytable 
                      group by mygroup 
                      having count > 50)
                )
```

Note that, *assuming that you want to delete all the results having mygroup count > 50*, this query won't do the full job. It will just return one row of that group. You should try this:

```
select * FROM mytable
where mygroup in (select mygroup 
                  from (select mygroup,
                               count(*) as count
                        from mytable
                        group by mygroup
                        having count > 1)
                  );
```

as stated in [D-Shish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52222053/6783663).

Here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/aaf03/3) to see the two different result set from these two queries.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete
from mytable
where rowid in (select rowid from (select rowid, count(*) as count from mytable group by mygroup having count > 50))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might want to do this when you use aggregate function you need to add non-aggregate column in `group by`

```
delete
from mytable
where mygroup in (select mygroup from mytable group by mygroup having count(*) > 50)
```